# Viewbag value is rendering in proper case. How do I force it to render in the intended case?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my controller I am setting a Viewbag value to `false` but when I render it on the view it comes out `False`. How do I prevent this?

My controller:

```
 ViewBag.IsEditable = false;
```

My view:

$.fn.editable.defaults.disabled =@ViewBag.IsEditable;

Because it is rendered with the Capital F in false the boolean doesn't work with my Jquery call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a boolean value that you want to evaluate in order to create some Javascript code.  In this case `@ViewBag.IsEditable` is basically calling `ToString()` on your boolean value, which produces capitalized True or False.

C# does have the lowercase keywords **true** and **false**, but they are literals which represent the Boolean object which always returns a capitalized True or False when `ToString()` is called on it.

I recommend using the ternary operator to evaluate the boolean.

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.disabled = @( ViewBag.IsEditable ? "true" : "false");
```

A clearer way of seeing what's going on here might be to write it like this:

```
@( ViewBag.IsEditable ?
  "$.fn.editable.defaults.disabled = true;" :
  "$.fn.editable.defaults.disabled = false;")
```

Comment: That worked but I'm still curious why the string case changed. ??

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing your types. `true` and `false` the keywords are boolean values. In the .NET world, the `.ToString()` represetation is "True" and "False", respectively. To keep your original code working, you could try

`$.fn.editable.defaults.disabled =@ViewBag.IsEditable.ToString().ToLower()`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider an extension method as a way of simplifying.  Note, you'd need to include the namespace for the extensions class in the view - either directly or via the web.config.  The flag would also need to be part of the model (or cast as bool so it can resolve the extension method)

```
   public static class BooleanExtensions
   {
        public static string AsJs(this bool source)
        {
            return source ? "true" : "false";
        }
   }
```

Used as

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.disabled = @(((bool)ViewBag.IsEditable).AsJs())
```

or

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.disabled = @Model.IsEditable.AsJs()
```